# How can I define these functions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I define these functions using absolute value, floor, ceiling, modulo, divides, and arithmetic operators?

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 1&~\text{ if 5 divides x }\\
 0&~ \text{if 5 does not divide x}
\end{cases}
$$

This is what I tried, but it only satisfies '1 if 5 divides x'.

f(x) = (x mod 5) + 1

Comment: How about $$\biggl\lfloor \frac{x}{5}\biggr\rfloor - \biggl\lfloor \frac{x-1}{5}\biggr\rfloor\,?$$

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x) = 1-(x^4 \bmod 5)$. This follows from Fermat's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Replaced $x$ with $|x|$ in case some program treats negative $x$ differently.

$f(x) := 1-\lceil \frac{|x| \mod 5}{5} \rceil.$

Comment: My computer says -7 mod 5 = -2, so your formula evaluates to -1 for x=-7.

Comment: @kimchilover That's weird. Then just replace $x$ with $|x|$.